# Log users in if mobile number authenticated in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm developing a website with mobile authentication. So, when user enters his mobile number on the login page, his mobile prompts a message and if he click OK, then page redirects to private area.

So, this is a Wordpress website. How to set cookies or do standard login stuff with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your are looking for two factor authentication, or as Wordpress calls it [Two Step Authentication](https://codex.wordpress.org/Two_Step_Authentication).

They have a few [recommended plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Two_Step_Authentication#Plugins_for_Two-Step_Authentication) that will handle this for you without rolling your own.